# How to replace the special character from the string in Apex

Tags: apex

We need to remove the all special character from the string in apex.

```
String s1 = 'a"b*c:5>x<y?z/de|f\'';
String regExp = '"*:<>?\/|\/‘;
String replacement = '1';
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(regExp, replacement);
System.debug(s2);
```

Above code shows,

> Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal `'"*:<>\/?|'`. Illegal character sequence `\/'` in string literal error.

How to remove the special character from the string in apex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include a character like backslash, you need to escape it.

Instead of:

```
'abc\def'
```

Use:

```
'abc\\def'
```

That will compile, but you have another problem. Your current approach searches for all the characters in sequence. You need to define a set of values using square brackets (`[...]`).

That said, if you want to remove non-alphanumeric text (aside from whitespace), you can use a simpler expression:

```
String regExp = '[^\\w\\s]';
```

What this expression says is find any single character which is not a word character or whitespace.

Comment: `\\w` includes underscore as well, just something for others to keep in mind.

Comment: @DerekF Indeed but the OP is not trying to replace underscores, so I didn't call that out specifically.